# Issues with Dynamic's second-argument functions

Tags: dynamic

First:

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) *`Dynamic[expr,f]` evaluates `f[val,expr]`  during interactive changing or editing*. Now check this example:

```
DynamicModule[{y, g},
 Column[{
   Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #; g = {#1, ##2}) &]],
   {"y", {"val", "expr"}},
   Dynamic[{y, g}]
   }]]
```

When you move the slider you will find there is a lag between `g[[1]] (val)` and `g[[2]] (expr)` .

My question is what controls and decides about this lag?

**Note:**

**I am not looking for solution of this (because one can do `Dynamic[expr,{f,fend}]`). Just I want to understand how does this behavior happen**

Second:

When we have three functions, *`Dynamic[expr,{fstart,f,fend}]` typically evaluates `fstart[val,expr]` once when the mouse is pressed, then evaluates `f[val,expr]` whenever the mouse is moved, and then evaluates `fend[val,expr]` once when the mouse is released*. 
Now check this example:

```
col = None; {Slider[
  Dynamic[x, {(col = Blue; x = #) &, (col = Red; 
      x = #) &, (col = Green) &}], Background -> Dynamic[col]], 
 Dynamic[x]}
```

It is clear (as I can see) when mouse is pressed, Blue color `Background`  does not show up which means the `fstart[val,expr]` is not evaluated.

Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 5):

The argument `##2` is simply evaluated to the current setting before it is passed to the function, and `#1` is the new setting.  For instance, if the new `val` is `0.2` and `expr` is `y`, whose current value is `0.1`, then `f[val, expr]` first becomes `f[0.2, 0.1]`, which then evaluates accordingly.

Compare with a function that holds its arguments, so that `y` will be evaluated after setting `y` to the new value:

```
DynamicModule[{y, g}, 
 Column[{Manipulator[
    Dynamic[y, Function[{v, e}, (y = v; g = {v, e}), HoldAll]]],
  {"y", {"val", "expr"}}, Dynamic[{y, g}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1, The second explanation (function with `HoldAll`)  is really interesting. could you let me know in the OP case, what decides about the lag value.

Comment: @Algohi The lag is the current vs. new settings (before the function evaluates): the 0.1 vs 0.2 in my answer.  `g` is set equal to the expression `{0.2, 0.1}`; it is not set equal to the expression `{0.2, y}`.  That is `##2` is `0.1` and not `y`.  Does that help? Or do you mean a different kind of lag?

Comment: What I meant is that in the OP when you move the slider you will notice that the difference between `val` and `expr` (`Differences@g`) is either `0.006` or `0.004`. I just want to know why specifically what chooses these values. Of course if the `Manipulator` range is different then the lag is different.

Comment: That is what I explained.  Before you click the mouse, `y` has a value in the slider.  Call it the "current value" `0.1`.  You move the slider to position `0.2`; call it the "new value".  Before the dynamic updating function is called then, `y` has the value `0.1` and it will eventually be set to `0.2` in the function. Let's abbreviate your function `(y = #; g = {#1, ##2}) &` by `f`.  Next the function is called: `f[0.2, y]`.  *Mathematica* first evaluates the arguments to get `f[0.2, 0.1]`, since `f` is not `HoldAll`. Finally `f` sets `y` to `0.2` and `g` to `{0.2, 0.1}`. Does that help?

Comment: @Algohi ...So the values chosen are the old value and whatever value you move the slider to.  There is a time lag between reads, so how far apart the values are depends on how fast you move the slider and how busy your computer is.

Comment: *"There  is a time lag between reads"* that is what I am trying to understand. Thanks

Comment: @Algohi A computer takes discrete steps at discrete intervals. Not only temporally does it read devices, such as a mouse, at discrete times, but spatially a mouse position is discretized, at a coarser level than floating-pt numbers, probably at pixel resolution, certainly by the computer system, and probably not discretized further by *Mathematica*.  You can diminish the spatial effect by holding down the option and shift keys. Aside from the effect of the keys, *Mathematica* probably does little else relative to the "lag" except rescale the image size to the numeric scale of the slider. HTH.

Comment: I would be happy if you add an answer to the second part of my question so that I can accept your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It appears that *`f`* beings immediately after *`fstart`* ends leaving no time for you to see the effect.

Consider

```
col = None;
{Slider[
  Dynamic[x,
   {(col = Blue; Print["Start"]; x = #) &,
    (col = Red; Print["Interactive"]; x = #) &,
    (col = Green) &}
   ], Background -> Dynamic[col]],
 Dynamic[x]}
```

When you press and hold the slider without moving it you immediately get the red background and output:

```
> Start
> Interactive
```

This shows that *`fstart`* is being called.

You can make use of `FinishDynamic` and `Pause` to get the affect you are looking for.

```
col = None;
{Slider[
  Dynamic[x,
   {(col = Blue; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[0.1]; x = #) &,
    (col = Red; x = #) &,
    (col = Green) &}
   ], Background -> Dynamic[col]],
 Dynamic[x]}
```

Now the background turns blue for a tenth of a second before turning red and manipulating the slider.

Hope this helps.